need to generate Cloudflare token in unit testing in backend
I have Django project which use Cloudflare turnsitle in Login and Signup apps.
I am tring to make a unit testing for the apps, but need to generate a Cloudflare token.
How can generate a new Cloudflare turnsitle token in each test.
from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate
from base_testing import BaseTestCase
from rest_framework import status
from signup.views import SignupView, BulkSignupView


class TestSignupView(BaseTestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        super().setUp()
        self.view = SignupView.as_view()
        self.data = {
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "user",
            "email": "testuser1@gmail.com",
            "password": "testpassword",
            "re_password": "testpassword",
            "company_name": "Testing Company",
            "token": "0.nKePu4sV_s9EXw6roPE-0Mo1q2ycQdHbku95SCTw3CgBO8Xv7IvLimFiBUd36WeMxnCTIcJ2b00MRuqM6ub5_WZsXzj0-A-9sxBtALKYEacFzg7uWCEHAwUCl7eIXNcqiG-JtkzEKP2wIxFFVHMRC2kzC9bcip7DHmg2Q_nynlCDJb3MWBs-GIzibRRdPqwgF5nLPhz0XD9MqMkorVwfaKVUlESwSOAo2AP222t5nZ13t3I2MC4HIe79zPdGPO8BL2Zf5o4L_z9PtS-GRkqtQBqO5rRMNnPgWexiSlI2SsslIW_Qo3cS_vg2UqHk_ywDU1aif6ofcmL4LcuX-I-PY4jmaSuKUAufVCCpYakE88MibDGhe6yKsfbTgETfTsvRs1LW1tWrF7kbmWADp3GF0rirPawrHnIKM7_dh5CzvTECdDkx41UrI65pbJmwZzww.ir38Pi8lyg-rzmLu91-7Rw.3c935db58384b2c356bd56d079a1f254603fb3d248f2270aa3b04c7890993576"
        }

I want to generate new token to send in self.date, how can make it?
